# Hive cannot find file from distributed cache on EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, emr, udf

I'm trying to run UDF in Hive, which basically should scan through external csv file using value from table as another argument. 
Query I use:

```
add jar s3://bucket_name/udf/hiveudf.jar;
add FILE hdfs:///myfile/myfile.csv;
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION MyFunc AS '....udf.myUDF';
SELECT mydate, record_id, value, MyFunc('myfile.csv',value) from my_table;
```

Results are unstable and in some cases exact same query works just fine, but in about 80% of cases it returns exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: myfile.csv (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
```

...

File seems to be added to distributed cache:

```
hive> list files;
/mnt/tmp/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx_resources/myfile.csv
```

I tried it with various releases of EMR as well as with various instance types and couldn't find a pattern or what triggers this issue. Any advise will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I am also facing same issue on EMR. Were you able to fix it ? I tried both ways - MyUDF("./MyFile.txt") and MyUDF("MyFile.txt"). I added some logging to print file path from UDF, It is trying to find file in "/user/home" dir.

Comment: Well, kind of. I was running my jobs by copy and paste Hive script into terminal window. My work around was - run same job from another terminal window and then it magically works, still unclear why it may matter...

Answer (score 0):

You might enable DEBUG to find more info. But in general, I've seen similar issues when there was a resize(shrink) on the EMR cluster causing certain blocks of expected HDFS distributed cache file removed from cluster  because of not enough replication.

Comment: Thanks, will try it. AWS tech support suggested so far to run statement immediately after adding files, because they assume that session where external files were added could be closed. Files will not be seen in this case. It sounds reasonable, but doesn't work in my case